# write to a file (and read from it later) an array of structure (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, arrays, file-io

I have an array of structure like this:

```
Structure Planner
        Dim Type As String        
        Dim Circuit As String
        Dim Socket As String
        Dim StepCMDText As String
    End Structure
```

how do i write it into a file? (also read it later ...)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use xml serialization that is available in VB.NET. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316730 for details.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as a csv file but simply iterating over a list and then separating each value by a comma otherwise you could serialise it and write that to a file.